# How to interact in terminal with the C program I just wrote

Tags: c, macos, terminal, variadic-functions

I just wrote a C program and I would like to know how to interact with it on the terminal.  My program consists of one function which is void and all that I have included in the main is the following:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    int arg;
    for (arg = 0; arg < argc; ++arg)
    {
        printf("Arg %d is %s\n", arg, argv[arg]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

My functions header is `void conv(int decimal, int y);`.

So could anybody give me some simple directions of how to do some conversions on the terminal on my Mac? I'm new to C and some help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is the code for `conv()`? What does it do? Where do you call it?

Comment: Assuming you saved your program in a file called `printargs.c`, you first compile it using the command line `cc -o printargs printargs.c`.  Then you can run your program using the command line `./printargs somearg someotherarg yetanotherarg`.

Comment: Your current code might be compiled into a program `arglist`, and at the terminal, you might run it as `./arglist arg1 'the second' "  this is the third. "` and you'd get 4 lines of output (one program name and 3 arguments).  How you integrate `conv()` into your program is up to you.  There are standard library functions to convert strings into numbers — `strtol()` from `<stdlib.h>` and its relatives, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Assume your program file is called `your_program.c`, then type the compiling command:

```
gcc your_program.c -o your_program
```

into terminal and enter. Then execute the program:

```
./your_program arg1 arg2...
```

Exactly, what is your specific question? I hope my answer helps you.

Comment: My specific question was "given the function I have (which is named conv with void return type) which accepts 2 integer arguments, what should I type in my main so that the function is implemented with argv[1] and argv[2]". For example I would be typing in ./main 8 2 and would want the 8 and 2 to be ran through the conv function.

Comment: argv[1] and argv[2] are strings, so you have to use atoi() or strtol() to convert argv[1] and argv[2] to integers and then pass them to your conv() function.